# Mac beeping every minute, exactly

Tags: macos

My Mac (a MacBook Air, though I doubt that's relevant) has for the last few weeks been beeping (giving the alert noise, that is) every minute, exactly.  It is getting to be extremely annoying, and I cannot find the cause.  Nothing is showing up in the Console log on a minute-by-minute basis, and there's no crontab entry to run every minute.  I've tried shutting down various programs and background processes to see if I can eliminate the source, but that hasn't turned up anything yet.

Once it starts I can't find any way to stop it, but apparently it is not 100% consistent, because (oddly enough!) it is not running right now.   Nonetheless, it happens often enough that in retrospect it *seems* like it happens all the time.  The only work-around I've found is to turn the alert volume all the way down, but of course that's not a solution since there are times when there are *real* alerts, and I want to hear those.

What could cause a Mac to beep every minute?

Comment: Do you have a clock widget installed ?

Comment: Have you tried login with a different user, to check if it happens too?

Comment: your battery is fully charged ?

Comment: @Buscar웃: no clock widgets--I don't use any widgets at all.  Re: the battery: do you mean that the alert is to tell me to unplug the cord because my battery is fully charged?  I'll try to see if there's any correlation with battery level...

Comment: @Thecafremo: good idea! as soon as it starts again I'll try logging in as Guest... I don't have any other users besides that.

Comment: I agree with @Thecafremo, try logging out and logging in as guest user. That will eliminate possible personal settings.

Comment: You have to be doing something to make it start ! It does not start if you just leave your computer alone for a while.

Answer (score 2):

[SoundBunny](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/soundbunny.php) is a new app that I have just learned about. There is a [free demo](http://www.prosofteng.com/downloads/download.php?prodID=88) available which will work for 15 days (I think).

The app window will show you every app which is makes a sound. That might help you track it down.

You can also tell it to ignore apps which you have ruled out, which should help you narrow things down a but too.

I hope that helps.

*(n.b. I am not related to this app except as a customer. The purpose of SoundBunny is to let you set the volume for each app, but I thought it might help with this as well.)*

Comment: Looks awesome, and from Prosoft Engineering, too!  The trial is for 30 days.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks.