# Macbook Air 2012 single beep while on

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Air 2012 is making a single beep during normal use. So far it has done this twice in the last 20 minutes so I don't know if there is an interval yet.

A cursory Google search only showed something about people having boot issues with multiple beeps when trying to start the machine. I am using this machine (it's already booted without issues) so I don't think that is relevant to me.

The machine isn't running hot, which would also be normal. So what does this beep mean? Insight appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to guess here. Do you have Notification, Reminder new email and so on, check those. Go to sounds and disable the User interface sound to test.

Comment: Can you describe the nature of the 'Beep'? Is it the standard system alert sound?

Answer (score 1):

[SoundBunny](http://www.prosofteng.com/downloads/download.php?prodID=88) has a [free demo](http://www.prosofteng.com/downloads/download.php?prodID=88) available which will work for 30 days, this app will show you every app which is makes a sound. That might help you track it down. You can also tell it to ignore apps which you have ruled out, which should help you narrow things down a but too. The purpose of SoundBunny is to let you set the volume for each app, but I thought it might help with this as well.

[TJ Luoma](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9226/tj-luoma) posted this answer to a similar question here: [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88755/mac-beeping-every-minute-exactly).